# Highcharts StockChart - xAxis data is different than data on Tooltip

Tags: timestamp, unix-timestamp

I'm having this issue and I multiplied timestamp from mysql query by 1000, its working, but problem is that inside tooltip it says 9 Nov and on xAxis its saying 10 Nov, 10 Nov is same as in database, I need it to be displayed as 10 Nov inside tooltip, somehow I managed to do that using tooltip formatter option but that line on chart when mousehoverd on it is somewhat behind 10th Nov, it must be on 10 Nov.

```
$('#chartViews').highcharts('StockChart', 
{

    rangeSelector: {
        inputEnabled: false
    },

    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    chart: {
        backgroundColor: '#24222B'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'date'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Views',
        data: json,
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
        }
    }]
});
```

Json string is:

> [[1414953000000,1],[1415039400000,2],[1415212200000,1],[1415557800000,1],[1415644200000,3]]

Comment: MYSQL UNIX_TIMESTAMP is converting 2014-11-03 from database as 1414953000, which when again converted to date is 2nd Nov (2014-11-02). Same is the case when I convert it using date php function. It seems that there is something wrong with the conversion process and not highcharts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was timezone issue, this is correct

> $x['date'] = (int)strtotime($x['timestamp'].' +5 hours 30 minutes') * 1000;

Comment: But still line is not on its date, its ahead the date on xaxis.

Comment: It might be because of GMT 5 Hours 30 minutes, now how to sync both dates one inside tooltip and other on xAxis.